# Why does (assoc-in everything ...) not change everything?

Tags: clojure

```
(def everything (vec (repeat 5 (vec (repeat 5 [0 0 0])))))

(assoc-in everything [3 3] [255 255 255])

(get-in everything [3 3])
```

This returns [0 0 0], not [255 255 255]. Why?

Comment: ...if you want to change state over time, you'll need to use a reference type -- an atom, a ref, etc -- and a call that updates it, such as `swap!` or `set!`. Updating a var is possible, but frowned on (for practical as well as theoretical/stylistic reasons -- performance is lousy, *and* humans reading your code won't expect it).

Comment: ...of course, one can also be changing the values one passes around with loop/recur, trampoline or the like without there being a reference type associated -- all a matter of what's appropriate for the job.

Answer (score 5):

Clojure data structures are immutable, so `assoc-in` does not change the vector, but returns a new vector with the changes. To have any affect, the results of `assoc-in` have to be captured in a binding, passed to a function, etc.

```
(get-in (assoc-in everything [3 3] [255 255 255]) [3 3])
;=> [255 255 255]
```

Note, due to structural sharing, the *new* vector is not a complete copy of the old with just one change, but a much smaller new tree, reusing much of the old vector.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are immutable. `assoc-in` when applied to an immutable data structure just returns a new data structure, and doesn't touch the original. You'll be wanting to give the return value a new name with, e.g., `(def foo (assoc-in everything [3 3] [255 255 255]))`, or else pass it to some other function or something.